# Excel macro to include parameter in Range

Tags: excel, copy, autofilter, vba

i am trying to write an excel macro, here is brief on what it does
1) open an excel file using input parameters, located on shared site.
2) filter based on input parms.
3) copies the filtered values to a new spreadsheet and sort them.

I see issue while writing selecting the range.

BuildID is input parameter

'converts column number to column name

```
ColNo = BuildID + 2
colnm = Split(Cells(, ColNo).Address(True, False), "$")
```

'Below section will filter the row 6 on Info tab and copy only those marked Change or New from input build ID

```
Rows("6:6").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
MsgBox (colnm)
cColNm = "colnm" & 6
MsgBox (cColNm)
Range("cColNm").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$IR$46").AutoFilter Field:="ColNo", Criteria1:="<>"
Range("A7:B45").Select
Selection.Copy
```

I am getting a type mismatch error at first msgbox.
(the colnm is working fine with the debug.print function which will print in immediate window but not store anywhere)
a similar msgbox worked in my earlier programs

can someone help me pointing what is wrong in this?

Comment: Try `MsgBox colnm` and `MsgBox cColNm`. The brackets are unnecessary. The auto-spacing inserted between *MsgBox* and *(* is trying to tell you that.

Comment: thanks Jeeped. i did that and even then it gave me an error...
I got the root cause.

split function in the excel macro given an array of elements.
i was trying to msgbox on an array without reference and hence it is failing...

i've corrected the code.. it looks like below.//


colnm = Split(Cells(, ColNo).Address(True, False), "$")(0)

'Below section will filter the row 6 on GeneralInfo tab and copy only those marked Change or New from input build ID

    Rows("6:6").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter = True
    MsgBox colnm
    cColNm = colnm & 6
    MsgBox cColNm

Comment: i have given the (0) which means the first element of that array
 colnm = Split(Cells(, ColNo).Address(True, False), "$")(0)

My bad i did not know split is an array. 
thank you very much for the help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks Jeeped.

i did remove the brackets in msgbox and even then it gave me an error... 
The root cuase for this is that i was trying to display an array using msgbox with no reference

split function in the excel macro gives an array of elements. 
i was trying to msgbox on an array without reference and hence it is failing...

i've corrected the code.. it looks like below.//

colnm = Split(Cells(, ColNo).Address(True, False), "$")(0)

'Below section will filter the row 6 on GeneralInfo tab and copy only those marked Change or New from input build ID

Rows("6:6").Select Selection.AutoFilter
MsgBox colnm 
cColNm = colnm & 6 
MsgBox cColNm

i have given the (0) which means the first element of that array

colnm = Split(Cells(, ColNo).Address(True, False), "$")(0)

My bad i did not know split is an array. thank you very much for the help.